# Is it possible for Netty to have 2 Pipelines / 2 Channels listening on the same port?

Tags: java, linux, unix, netty, nio

I am wondering if it is possible to have two different ChannelPipeline, getting bootstrapped with the same local port?

The way I set up my pipeline is through ClientBootstrap.connect(remoteAddress). I didn't provide a local port. In this case, I think the OS will manage the local port assignment for me. Is it possible that if I run out of available port or for some other reason, I end up getting two pipelines or two channels listening to the same local port?

If thats possible, and if that local port receives a message, which pipeline will receive & handle that message? Or both pipeline will get notified and handle it?

Thanks!
Erben

Comment: It isn't possible in TCP unless the underlying sockets are explicitly bound to different IP addresses, in which case your final question doesn't arise.

Comment: Hi @EJP, I am using TCP. if I understand you correctly, you are saying that I can have two channels with the same local address but different remote address?